# Which tag should be used in Ionic 1.3 app ion tags or html tags with ionic classes?

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am building an app in ionic 1.3. I have good knowledge of angular 1, javascript and css. However this is my first ionic app. I went through many ionic 1 tutorials and also ionic site doc. They uses html div tag with ionic built in classes to create ionic components e.g., `<div class="bar bar-header">`. However when i installed sample project using command `ionic start myApp tabs` it uses ion tags everywhere intead of div tags

In ionic website docs i saw that they uses these tags in ionic 2.

Now i want to ask which tags are better to use with ionic 1.3. because some tags such as `<ion-badge` are now working with this. so should i replace whole project code with div tags or should continue with

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I use both in my case.

Ionic's directive is encapsulation. Some situations, using theirs are convenient, such as `ion-menu`、`ion-content`、`ion-nav-title` ... and so on.

Recommend that you using theirs if provided to have a native experience. But you can override always yourself. After all, it's just a webpage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer benny. why <ion-badge is not working. should i use <div class="badge" instead. or is badge tag is not available in ionic 1

Comment: @VinitSingh Because there's no <ion-badge> directive! That's easy to understand! see the reference http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/ (That's called `AngularJS Extensions`)